# Show whether the set of all functions $\{f : {1, 2, 3} → ℕ \}$ is countable (i.e. countably infinite) or not

Tags: real-analysis

I need help showing whether this is countable (i.e. countably infinite) or not. I know I need to show that there is a bijection between the set of all functions $\{f : {1, 2, 3} → ℕ \}$ and $ℕ$ but I don't know where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's $|\Bbb N|^3$, surely? That's countable.

Comment: @Shaun can you please elaborate on this

Answer (score 1):

An interesting angle to approach this problem with is through prime factorizations.

Let $A$ be the set of all functions $\{f: \{1, 2, 3\} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}\}$. Say that a function $g \in A$ is defined as follows:

$$g(1) = 6$$
$$g(2) = 4$$
$$g(3) = 13$$

We could "encode" this function's definition in the products of primes. For example, we could map $g$ to $2^6 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 5^{13}$ (if your definition of the naturals includes $0$, then you need to slightly modify this concept to avoid $0$th powers). If you are consistent with the primes you use and their order, then you could map any function from $A$ to a natural number, and because prime factorizations are unique, this is an injection from $A$ to the naturals.

From here, we simply need to find an injection from the naturals to $A$, which can be done fairly trivially, and by Schröder–Bernstein we have demonstrated the necessary bijection to prove $A$ is countable.

Probably not the most elegant or straightforward way to prove this fact, but I always found proofs like this neat, so I figured I'd share.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I can see a way to prove the statement by using your advice.